# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword displayName returned null

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a new user with email and password using firebase auth. However, when I try to access the displayName and from the returned async call I get a null value (before updateProfile function). To get a way around it, I am passing in the username in the function which is the displayName. I am also trying to create a new document inside the collection users. In order to have access to all the fields I had to have .then after the updateProfile function which I feel is not the right way of doing. Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
async signUp(email: string, password: string, username: string, phoneNumber: string){
    await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/home'])
        return result.user?.updateProfile({
          displayName: username
        })
          .then( () => {
            this.afs.collection("users").doc(result.user?.uid).set({
              uid: result.user?.uid,
              displayName: result.user?.displayName,
              phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
              photoURL: result.user?.photoURL,
              providerId: result.user?.providerId,
            })
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      })
  }
```

Comment: You could directly pass `username` itself to Firestore document. or try using reload after setting the name `result.user.reload()`

Comment: Can you make changes to the code above? I am kinda confused.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the user profile is an asynchronous operation and does not automatically refresh the Firebase Authentication user profile in your app. The `displayName` property of the user profile won't be set until you either [force it to refresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#userreload), until up to an hour has passed, or until the user signs in again.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your reply. So instead of updateProfile, I should change it to reload()?

Comment: No, you need to do both. Calling `updateProfile` updates the profile on the server only. The other options then pull that update to the client.

Comment: Gotcha so this is what I have as of now, result.user?.updateProfile() and then result.user?.reload()? Is this correct?